# Use a directive to display data from scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

I'm trying to understand how directives are working but I'm running into a bug pretty soon.

I've created a codepen of my example [here](http://codepen.io/alucardu/pen/jbpQWr)

I've created a scope called movies which has 3 movies in it. I want to display these titles through the directive.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.movies = [
    {
      title: 'Star Wars',
      release_date: '10-11-2015'
    }, {
      title: 'Spectre',
      release_date: '25-12-2015'
    }, {
      title: 'Revenant',
      release_date: '02-03-2016'
    }
  ];
});
```

And I've created a directive.

```
app.directive('movieOverview', function () {
  return {
    template: 'Name: {{movie.title}}',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  };
});
```

And this is the haml code,

```
%html{"ng-app" => "plunker"}
  %body{"ng-controller" => "MainCtrl"}
    %movie-Overview
```

The directive does work (somewhat) since the `Name:` gets displayed on the page. Just not the results from the scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is not any scope variable with name `movie`, you should iterate over each object the you will have access to each element of `movies` & then you can display the `movie` name by changing your template to below.

```
template: '<div ng-repeat="movie in movies">Name: {{movie.title}}</div>',
```

Also directive should have using `small-case` as like `movie-overview` instead of `movie-Overview`

**OR**

If you don't want to change directive then do change directive & iterate it with the `ng-repeat` so you don't need to change directive

```
%html{"ng-app" => "plunker"}
  %body{"ng-controller" => "MainCtrl"}
    %movie-overview {"ng-repeat" => "movie in movies"}
```

Comment: Thanks Pankaj, I took an example from http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-i-the-fundamentals in which the Directive doesn't have the ng-repeat. So I thought it wasnt needed.

Comment: @PeterBoomsma I think the updated answer in **OR** section would make sense too..

Comment: @OankajParkar I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean with in OR.

Comment: @PeterBoomsma OR in the sense I wanted to notify my second part of an answer..Got it?

Comment: Ah yes didn't see that. Makes sence. But I do need to use the directive.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems I see.

Firstly, in your template you are referring to movie.title, while in your controller you create an array of objects and assign it to movies.  The reason you only see `Name:` and not a movie title is because movie doesn't exist in the scope.  If you change your directive to

```
app.directive('movieOverview', function () {
  return {
    template: 'Name: {{movies[0].title}}',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  };
});
```

you should see the title of the first movie in the movies array.

Second, I imagine you want to display all the movies since you have an array of them.  Easiest way to do that is to put an `ng-repeat` directive in your template.  So if you want to show all movies do something like this

```
app.directive('movieOverview', function () {
  return {
    template: '<p ng-repeat="movie in movies">Name: {{movie.title}}</p>',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  };
});
```

This will repeat the `<p>` tag for each movie in your array and you should see a list of three movies on your page.

Comment: Thanks Dustin, I took an example from http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-i-the-fundamentals in which the Directive doesn't have the ng-repeat. So I thought it wasnt needed.

Comment: It's not needed unless you need it :).  In general if you have a collection of objects and want to display all of them you will need some sort of repeating directive.  The most common is ngRepeat